# How can I prevent file execution in a specific folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security

I don't want to inadvertently execute programs in my "Downloads" folder. How do I do that in Windows 7 Home Premium?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right-click on the Downloads folder in your user folder and select **Properties**.  Select the **Security tab**, then click the **Advanced** button:

[image]

Click the **Change Permissions...** button:

[image]

Select the entry for your user name and click **Edit**:

[image]

Set the **Deny** checkbox for the **Traverse folder / execute file** entry:

[image]

Click OK to close all windows.

Comment: It took a bit more dialog boxes, but I managed to do that. Thank you!

Comment: @Ramalhão: Answer edited to reflect correct procedure, my original answer wasn't quite correct.